# Клиент Redis выдает ошибку redis: nil

Tags: golang, redis

Пишу обертку клиента *Redis* для кеширования данных, загружаемых из online сервисов:

```
import (
    "github.com/go-redis/redis/v7"
)

type Cache struct {
    client *redis.Client
}

// Инициализация из примера в документации
func NewRedisClient() *redis.Client {
    return redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
    })
}    

func NewAudioCache() *Cache {
    ret := &Cache{client: service.NewRedisClient()}
    // ret.client.HSet("test", ExclKey, "C")
    // log.Println(ret.client.HGetAll("test").Result())
    return ret
}

func (c *Cache) ExclusionsByProcessor(processor common.ProcessorType) ([]string, error) {
    res, err := c.client.HGet(ExclKey, processor.String()).Result()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return strings.Split(res, ","), nil
}
```

На хосте с *golang 1.12/SparkyLinux* вызов методов обертки работает корректно, а на *golang 1.13/ArchLinux* выдает ошибку `redis: nil` в `ExclusionsByProcessor()` и прочих методах.

`Ping()` работает везде. Закомментированный код в `NewAudioCache()` также работает.

Comment: Не видно, где вы этот ключ устанавливаете.  `redis.Nil` значит, что пол ключу нету ничего.

Comment: Вы оказались правы: не было ключа. На первом хосте я вручную проигрывал ситуацию и у меня он был для мапа, а на втором хосте - нет. Спасибо.

Comment: Если дело было действительно в этом, примите ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка `redis.Nil` означает, что в БД по этому ключу
ничего нет.  Убедитесь, что ключ существует, например через
`redis-cli`.